# Key and Value from property bag SharePoint .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I want to access the property bag and list the key and values in a web part.

```
 using (SPSite RootSite = new SPSite(URL))
 {
  using (SPWeb rootWeb = RootSite.OpenWeb())
  {
     rootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
       string myValue = rootWeb.AllProperties["MyKey"].ToString();
      lblProperties.Text = myValue;
  );
```

This is not working tho, why?

Thanks

Comment: What isn't working?  Do you get an error, is the result not what you expected, or what?  Are you sure there is a property with that key in the bag?

Comment: Oh, I don't think there's anything in the bag now when you say it. Will check that. 

But how do I read everything that's in the bag (rootwWeb.Allproperties[""]?)? Or do I have to set properties before? They're not created automatically?

Sorry for the stupid questions, kinda new on this prop bag stuff.

Thanks

Comment: The indexer is used to get a property from the bag, or set a value in the bag.  Look at all of the other methods/properties the object has to see what else you can do with it.  You cannot get the value of a property that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access a key that doesn't exist, this is resulting in the value being returned being `null`, which will throw when you call `ToString` on it.  Either check to make sure that the key exists first using `ContainsKey`, or handle `null` when using the value.